# Menus and toolbar went missing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, toolbar

I have mostly been using ArcGIS Pro lately and I went back to an old map in ArcMap 10.8 for the first time in a while and the menu bar and tool bars are missing.

[image: top left corner of ArcMap screen]

I can't find them and I have no idea what happened. I reinstalled ArcMap hoping that would restore the defaults.

Can anyone tell me how to bring them back?

Answer (score 2):

A single toolbar was undocked and floating behind another window, found it by closing everything else on my machine. I right clicked the header of the floating toolbar, which brought up the toolbar customization menu.

[image]

Then I selected all the missing toolbars, docked them and arrange them how I prefer.

[image]

I am still not sure how this happened, but am glad it was simple enough to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem after restart my computer for updates, but I Didn't found any undocked and floating toolbar in order to solve it as you did.

I fixed it by resetting ArcMap to its default settings - I did it by renaming the **normal.mxt** file (which stores user interface customizations). I located The file in the "AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.x\ArcMap\Templates" folder, and renamed it to "normal.mxt.old". Then, I restarted ArcMap, and the toolbars were displayed.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!